# Move csproj file Configurations to other file

Tags: visual-studio

VS sets automatically my configuration inside csproj. I can also modify them from there, but last times this file works really bad. Any way to move this to another file that will not be overwritten when I build the solution, something cleaner? something like myConfig.cs

I use the configurations to set the version of the References that I´m loading. I use Revit as external software to run the applications, so many times I have to switch the Revit´s DLL version in order to get the correct one. I´m interested in include only this information.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '2019|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\2019\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>2019</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '2018|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\2018\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>2018</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '2020|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\2020\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>2020</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>



    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '2018'">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2018\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '2018'">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2018\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '2019'">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPIUI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '2019'">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\RevitAPIUI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RevitAPI" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '2020'">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\RevitAPI.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
```

Any documentation/sample where I can see how could I do this?
Other recommendations to handle this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: What are you suing.  Web/Win/Forms, MVC, .net core?

Comment: I´m using .NET Framework 4.7.2.
I started the project as a Class Library.

Comment: There should be no configuration in class library.  What kind of config are you talking about?

Comment: I have added some code in the question, these are what I would like to move to another cs file.

Comment: These references to dll files should never change.  The best approach is to make a solution folder put the dlls in there and then reference them.  That way the path will stay relative